# Is offsetof of a union member always zero?

Tags: c++, unions

Does C++ guarantee that `offsetof(U, m)` always returns zero for any union `U` and its member `m` or are there cases when it's non-zero?

```cpp
union U {
  M m;
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's always zero.
[6.8.2.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
> — they are the same object, or
> — one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> — one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object ([class.mem]), or
> — there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_­cast. [Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. — end note]

Since they are pointer-interconvertible and share the same address, `offsetof(U, m)` should be zero.

**Update:**

If the union `U` is not standard-layout, it's conditionally-supported. [17.2.4.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#1):

> The macro offsetof(type, member-designator) has the same semantics as the corresponding macro in the C standard library header <stddef.h>, but accepts a restricted set of type arguments in this document. Use of the offsetof macro with a type other than a standard-layout class ([class.prop]) is conditionally-supported.183 The expression offsetof(type, member-designator) is never type-dependent and it is value-dependent if and only if type is dependent. The result of applying the offsetof macro to a static data member or a function member is undefined. No operation invoked by the offsetof macro shall throw an exception and noexcept(offsetof(type, member-designator)) shall be true.

But once it be supported, the only result make sense is zero since they share the same address.

Comment: @HTNW By [11.2.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#5), a standard-layout union is a standard-layout class. But if it's not standard-layout, as you say, it may be non-defined.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a guarantee of this if your union is [*standard-layout*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout):

> [`[class.mem/26]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#26.sentence-1): If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member if that member is not a bit-field. *[..]*

This is okay, because if it *isn't* standard-layout, you probably don't want to be using `offsetof` anyway:

> [`[support.types.layout/1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#1.sentence-2): Use of the `offsetof` macro with a type other than a standard-layout class ([class.prop]) is conditionally-supported.

(It has undefined behaviour in C, and until C++17.)

Comment: @HTNW [Unions are absolutely class types.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#1)